# Flask login for REST API and Web application both

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-jwt-extended

I want to do a Flask application with both REST API and Web Application.
For example, my application will have **protected** routes:

- `/notes` - for viewing all notes of user
- `/notes/<note_id>` - for viewing ceratin note

And same **protected** routes but in REST API:

- `/api/notes`
- `/api/notes/<note_id>`

Now I want to implement register and login functions. I know that for Web Application part there is library `Flask-Login` for that purpose. For REST API part I know I can use `Flask-JWT-Extended`.

But, what if I want to make AJAX request from `/notes/1` to `/api/notes`? To load all user notes on page **after** page load.
I will need JWT token of user to make such request. Is it always neccessary to make request to `/api/login` first every time? Or I can use `Flask-Login` somehow to work using same JWT tokens REST API part uses and store JWT-tokens somewhere after user goes to page `/notes/1` in his browser, allowing JS script to use it after page loading to make AJAX requests to protected API routes?